# Why not changed uibutton title programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton on the screen and i would like to change this title at start.
i tried this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addCardCenterBtn: UIButton!
func roundedButton(){
    self.addCardCenterBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
    self.addCardCenterBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * addCardCenterBtn.bounds.size.width
    self.addCardCenterBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.addCardCenterBtn.setTitle("AS", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

override public func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    roundedButton()
}
```

but its not working, and i dont know why. In storyboard i connected to the viewcontroller my button.

Comment: you can see the code in my question

Comment: Remove this line `self.addCardCenterBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton`. Because it is already initialised.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thanks! But i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line `self.addCardCenterBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton`.

Because it is already initialised. When you connect any control from storyboard to ViewController, never initialise it again. Just make the changes to it and the new changes will take effect.